# ¿COMO PUEDO HACER UNA CONEXION DE UNA BASE DE DATOS DE ORACLE CON VISUAL ESTUDIO CON ENTITY FRAMEWORK?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un problema ya que al querer conectar con una base de datos de Oracle que es SQL developer ,usando el Microsoft visual studio al querer cambiar el origen de datos no me da la opción de Oracle, si no que  tiene el por defecto el de SQL server.

intente probar con un ODAC que  vi en internet pero no me funciono

Comment: bienvenido, recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste en tu pregunta, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Chris... Bienvenido al sitio. Una pregunta, qué palabras utilizaste cuando buscaste en google? Yo escribí *connect ef core to oracle* y me arrojó [muchos resultados útiles](https://www.google.com/search?q=connect+ef+core+to+oracle&oq=connect+ef+core+to+oracle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30.29423j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)